# Does creating a new shell via bash -c passes environment

Tags: bash, environment-variables

Assuming we want to run multiple bash commands via

```
bash -c "command1 && command2 || command3"
```

Will the new shell inherit the environment of the `bash -c` command?

Comment: Sorry, what is "the new shell" that you are referring to?  The `bash -c` shell will inherit the environment of the calling shell, and the commands within will inherit the environment of the `bash -c` shell that they are started from.

Comment: @Kusalananda: doesn't `bash -c` create a "new shell" (in the sense of a "new process")?

Comment: @sdbbs This was a few years ago, but I believe I questioned why the user mentions "the new shell" and "the `bash -c` command" separately (the former inheriting the environment from the latter).

Answer (score 1):

Environment variables will be available to the new process.  The private shell variables will not.